# > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am not able to run my react-native project on an android device using:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

When i run the above command in powershell, it shows me this error:

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Comment: Please add a proper title for your question. Your title is not clear enough to justify your problem. Please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask good question.

Comment: Please add logs about error from your terminal after run `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

```
cd android

./gradlew clean

cd ..

npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

try to open in android studio, build again, you will see error to solve.
in my case, the app require app_id when I install Onesignal in build grade